# Clip a number to the numeric limits of another type using the closest value according to linear order

Tags: c++

Using C++, I want to clip a number to the numeric limits of another arithmetic type which might be smaller than the source type. Constraint is, that the resulting value should be the closest value to the source value in the linear order of the integer set.

- a number which is below the minimum limit of the target type should be converted to that minimum limit
- a number which is larger than the maximum limit of the target type should be converted to that maximum limit
- should work for built-in integer and floating point types (I did not look at multiple-precision types from 3rd party libraries)

Examples:

- a negative number converted to an unsigned should return `0`
- an unsigned `65'535` converted to an int16 should return `32'767`

Use case: The consumer of a library is interested only in a fraction of the provided numeric range. To safely handle numbers which are outside of the targeted range, the conversion needs to match above constraints (therefore casting is not an option).

### Implementation (requires C++17)

This is what I came up with:

```
#include <limits>

template <typename T>
constexpr T clip(T v, T lo, T hi)
{
    return (v < lo) ? lo : (hi < v) ? hi : v;
}

template <typename TargetType, typename SourceType>
constexpr TargetType clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits(SourceType v)
{
    // This condition is necessary to not break integer -> floating point conversion
    // (the `static_cast<SourceType>(lo/hi)` below will give unwanted results),
    // while at the same time still clipping floating point type -> shorter floating point type.
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<TargetType>::value
        && !(
            std::is_floating_point<SourceType>::value
            && (std::numeric_limits<SourceType>::max_exponent
                >= std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::max_exponent)
            )
        )
    {
        return static_cast<TargetType>(v);
    }
    else
    {
        constexpr auto lo = std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::min();
        constexpr auto hi = std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::max();
        constexpr auto lo_sourceType = static_cast<SourceType>(lo);
        constexpr auto hi_sourceType = static_cast<SourceType>(hi);
        return static_cast<TargetType>(clip<SourceType>(v, lo_sourceType, hi_sourceType));
        // ... cannot use std::clamp, since it might assert when (lo_sourceType > hi_sourceType)
        // return static_cast<TargetType>(std::clamp(v, lo_sourceType, hi_sourceType));
    }
}
```

### Questions

1. Is there an implementation doing that already available in boost or other library (I looked, but wasn't able to find one)?
2. Instead of the `if constexpr` condition, it might be cleaner to just disallow the call of the function for an *integral source type* and a *floating point target type*. This might also make it compatible with C++11/14. How `std::enable_if` could be used to check for both the source and the target type?
3. C++20 concepts will make compile errors more readable. How this function would look like with concepts? (should the `if constexpr` condition be removed and replaced by a concept similar to the question before?)
4. Do you see possible unexpected behaviour?

Thanks!

---

### Test

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template <typename SourceType, SourceType s,
          typename TargetType, TargetType expectedResult>
void test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits()
{
    constexpr auto result = clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<TargetType>(s);
    std::cout << s << " -> " << +result << std::endl;
    static_assert(expectedResult == result);
}

template <typename SourceType, typename TargetType, typename S, typename T>
void test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits(S f_s, T f_expectedResult)
{
    constexpr auto s = f_s();
    constexpr auto expectedResult = f_expectedResult();
    constexpr auto result = clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<TargetType>(s);
    std::cout << s << " -> " << +result << std::endl;
    static_assert(expectedResult == result);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\n--- negative signed integer -> unsigned ---" << std::endl;
    test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<
        int32_t,    -42,                // source value
        uint32_t,     0>();             // expected result

    std::cout << "\n--- integer -> shorter integer type ---" << std::endl;
    test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<
        uint32_t,   UINT32_MAX,         // source value
        uint16_t,   UINT16_MAX>();      // expected result
    test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<
        uint32_t,   UINT32_MAX,         // source value
        char,       INT8_MAX>();        // expected result
    test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<
        int64_t,    INT32_MIN + 42,     // source value
        int32_t,    INT32_MIN + 42>();  // expected result

    std::cout << "\n--- floating point -> integer ---" << std::endl;
    test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<
        float,
        unsigned>(
            [](){ return -42.7f; },         // source value
            [](){ return   0; });           // expected result
    test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<
        double,
        uint8_t>(
            [](){ return 1024.5; },         // source value
            [](){ return UINT8_MAX; });     // expected result

    std::cout << "\n--- floating point -> shorter floating point type ---" << std::endl;
    test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<
        double,
        float>(
            [](){ return std::numeric_limits<double>::min(); }, // source value
            [](){ return std::numeric_limits<float>::min(); }); // expected result

    test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<
        long double,
        float>(
            [](){ return std::numeric_limits<long double>::max(); }, // source value
            [](){ return std::numeric_limits<float>::max(); });      // expected result

    std::cout << "\n--- integer -> floating point ---" << std::endl;
    test_clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<
        uint64_t,
        float>(
            [](){ return UINT64_MAX; },     // source value
            [](){ return UINT64_MAX; });    // expected result

    std::cout << "\n--- to bool ---" << std::endl;
    constexpr auto b_f = clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<bool>(0);
    std::cout << 0 << " -> " << std::boolalpha << b_f << std::endl;
    static_assert(0 == b_f);
    constexpr auto ldbl_max = std::numeric_limits<long double>::max();
    constexpr auto b_t = clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<bool>(ldbl_max);
    std::cout << ldbl_max << " -> " << std::boolalpha << b_t << std::endl;
    static_assert(1 == b_t);

    std::cout << "\n--- evaluation at runtime ---" << std::endl;
    const auto duration_ticks = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    const auto i8_at_runtime = clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits<int8_t>(duration_ticks);
    std::cout << duration_ticks << " -> " << +i8_at_runtime << std::endl;
    assert(INT8_MAX == i8_at_runtime);
}
```

Possible output:

```sh
--- negative signed integer -> unsigned ---
-42 -> 0

--- integer -> shorter integer type ---
4294967295 -> 65535
4294967295 -> 127
-2147483606 -> -2147483606

--- floating point -> integer ---
-42.7 -> 0
1024.5 -> 255

--- floating point -> shorter floating point type ---
2.22507e-308 -> 1.17549e-38
1.18973e+4932 -> 3.40282e+38

--- integer -> floating point ---
18446744073709551615 -> 1.84467e+19

--- to bool ---
0 -> false
1.18973e+4932 -> true

--- evaluation at runtime ---
1585315690266730 -> 127
```

Comment: One question by question please.

Comment: 1. seems off topics, What have you tried for 2.. I indeed see 2. and 3. with 2 functions instead of 1.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand that complex constexpr condition - the comment does not seem to match any of the existing code.

I also did not examine the logic very carefully either.

Anyhow, instead of trying to figure out what you are trying to do, I decided to just address the issue of C++17 being required due to using constexpr-if.

There are LOTS of way to accomplish this...  I'll just show three possibilities...

In each, I just left your condition the same as you wrote it.

The first with enable if, though it is much easier to read if you make a metafunction first.

```cpp
namespace detail {
template <typename TargetT, typename SourceT>
struct IsFloatConversion
: std::bool_constant<
    std::is_floating_point<TargetT>::value
        && !(std::is_floating_point<SourceT>::value
                && (std::numeric_limits<SourceT>::max_exponent
                    >= std::numeric_limits<TargetT>::max_exponent))>
{
};
}
template <typename TargetType, typename SourceType>
constexpr
std::enable_if_t<detail::IsFloatConversion<TargetType, SourceType>::value,
        TargetType>
clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits(SourceType v)
{
    return static_cast<TargetType>(v);
}
template <typename TargetType, typename SourceType>
constexpr
std::enable_if_t<not detail::IsFloatConversion<TargetType, SourceType>::value,
        TargetType>
clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits(SourceType v)
{
    constexpr auto lo = std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::min();
    constexpr auto hi = std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::max();
    constexpr auto lo_sourceType = static_cast<SourceType>(lo);
    constexpr auto hi_sourceType = static_cast<SourceType>(hi);
    return static_cast<TargetType>(
        clip<SourceType>(v, lo_sourceType, hi_sourceType));
}
```

The second way is just tag dispatch.

```cpp
namespace detail {
template <typename TargetType, typename SourceType>
constexpr TargetType
clipToTargetTypeNumericLimitsImpl(SourceType v, std::true_type)
{
    return static_cast<TargetType>(v);
}
template <typename TargetType, typename SourceType>
constexpr TargetType
clipToTargetTypeNumericLimitsImpl(SourceType v, std::false_type)
{
    constexpr auto lo = std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::min();
    constexpr auto hi = std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::max();
    constexpr auto lo_sourceType = static_cast<SourceType>(lo);
    constexpr auto hi_sourceType = static_cast<SourceType>(hi);
    return static_cast<TargetType>(
        clip<SourceType>(v, lo_sourceType, hi_sourceType));
}
}
template <typename TargetType, typename SourceType>
constexpr TargetType clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits(SourceType v)
{
    constexpr bool dofloat = std::is_floating_point<TargetType>::value
        && !(
            std::is_floating_point<SourceType>::value
            && (std::numeric_limits<SourceType>::max_exponent
                >= std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::max_exponent)
            );
    return detail::clipToTargetTypeNumericLimitsImpl<TargetType>(v,
        std::integral_constant<bool, dofloat>{});
}
```

And the third is similar, but uses specialization.

```cpp
namespace detail {
template <bool>
struct Clip
{
    template <typename TargetType, typename SourceType>
    static constexpr TargetType _ (SourceType v)
    {
        return static_cast<TargetType>(v);
    }
};
template <>
struct Clip<false>
{
    template <typename TargetType, typename SourceType>
    static constexpr TargetType _ (SourceType v)
    {
        constexpr auto lo = std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::min();
        constexpr auto hi = std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::max();
        constexpr auto lo_sourceType = static_cast<SourceType>(lo);
        constexpr auto hi_sourceType = static_cast<SourceType>(hi);
        return static_cast<TargetType>(
            clip<SourceType>(v, lo_sourceType, hi_sourceType));
    }
};
}
template <typename TargetType, typename SourceType>
constexpr TargetType clipToTargetTypeNumericLimits(SourceType v)
{
    constexpr bool dofloat = std::is_floating_point<TargetType>::value
        && !(
            std::is_floating_point<SourceType>::value
            && (std::numeric_limits<SourceType>::max_exponent
                >= std::numeric_limits<TargetType>::max_exponent)
            );
    return detail::Clip<dofloat>::template _<TargetType>(v);
}
```

There are other ways, but that should give you enough to choose something you like - or build something you like better.